# Background image not visible on the device in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

.scss here

```
.login_back{
  background-image: url('../../assets/img/applogback.png');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When I'm running app using ionic serve --lab it works.but cannot see the background image in ionic view or the app build.What is the best way to over come this issue!

Comment: Use Remote Debugging - Android and Chrome to inspect your app on device. More info  [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/developer-tips/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the image is wrong. Try with this:

```
.login_back{
  background-image: url('../assets/img/applogback.png');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It was exactly the solution I needed when using Ionic 3 and trying to set a custom background image. Thank you sebaferras

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure of why it was downvoted (or not even upvoted by the owner of the question in the first place), but I'm glad to hear that it helped you :)